# Can't get into App Service Editor today. What's going on?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am in the portal on my Function blade and click "Go to App Service Editor".

I get message: "You are not authorized or do not have any subscriptions associated with your account."

I've never had that message before in this context.

Comment: Are you able to go to the root of the scm site (i.e. Kudu) on the same Web App? i.e. just remove dev from the URL. If not, then issue is not directly related to App Service Editor, but likely more scm authentication in general.